# How do I negate an ut clause of result?

Tags: idiom, grammar-choice, ut, negation

*Ut* clauses of result are excellent for saying "so ___ that". But what if I wanted to reverse this and say "not ___ enough to"?

For example, *tam strenue laborābam ut epistolās centum scripserim* means "I worked so hard that I got one hundred letters written". What if I wanted to contrast myself with Pseudolus, who *didn't* work hard enough to get one hundred letters written?

(Note that I'm not looking for a simple *ut…non*, which to my understanding would be something like "I worked so hard that I didn't get one hundred letters written". I want to negate the working hard, rather than just the writing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you can use (*non*) *satis* with a result clause to mean 'not *x* enough to (do *y*)':

> *non satis strenue laborabam ut centum epistulas scripserim.*
>
> I didn't work hard enough to (manage to) write 100 letters.

I didn't go through every search result, but the only example I managed to find of this construction (as opposed to other places where *satis* is followed by an *ut* clause of a different sort) is Seneca the Younger, *Epistulae morales ad Lucilium* 52.2:

> ***nemo per se satis valet ut emergat**; oportet manum aliquis porrigat, aliquis educat.*
>
> No one is strong enough to rise to prominence by himself….

Here are some other options, somewhat better attested than the preceding:

- Replace *tam* in your original main clause with *adeo non*, and then negate the result clause too:

  > *adeo non strenue laborabam ut centum epistolas non scripserim.*
  >
  > To such a degree did I not work hard that I didn't (manage to) write 100 letters.'

  Cf. Pliny the Younger, *Epistulae* 1.8.10:

  > ***oculorum porro et aurium uoluptates adeo non egent commendatione, ut non tam incitari debeant oratione quam reprimi**; ut uero aliquis libenter educationis taedium laboremque suscipiat, non praemiis modo uerum etiam exquisitis adhortationibus impetrandum est.*
  >
  > To such a degree do pleasures for the eye and ear not require approval, that they should not so much be encouraged as restrained in a speech….

  Also, Seneca the Younger, *Epistulae morales ad Lucilium* 18.1:

  > *December est mensis: cum maxime civitas sudat. ius luxuriae publice datum est; ingenti apparatu sonant omnia, tamquam quicquam inter Saturnalia intersit et dies rerum agendarum; **adeo nihil interest ut <non> videatur mihi errasse qui dixit olim mensem Decembrem fuisse, nunc annum**.*
  >
  > …To such a degree is there not any difference that he doesn't seem to have been mistaken who said that December was once a month but is now a year.
- Use this somewhat uncommon but perfectly sound construction: *tantum abest* with two result clauses, 'It is so far from being the case that *x* occurs, that *y* occurs.'

  As explained in Allen & Greenough §571.b, one of the two result clauses (= *x* in the preceding translation) 'is *substantive*, the subject of **abest**; the other [= *y*] is *adverbial*, correlative with **tantum**.' In this case, the latter result clause is negated.

  In other words, you could say:

  > *tantum afuit ut strenue laborarem ut centum epistulas non scripserim.*
  >
  > So far was I from working hard, that I didn't (manage to) write 100 letters.

  Cf. Livy, *Ab urbe condita* 44.38.4:

  > *nam tantum abest, ut me hesternae quietis paeniteat, ut servatum a me exercitum eo consilio credam.*
  >
  > For so far am I from regretting my lack of action yesterday, that I believe that I saved the army by my plan.
- Replace *strenue* with some adverb that's opposite in meaning, such as *pigre*, and then negate the result clause:

  > *tam pigre laborabam ut centum epistulas non scripserim.*
  >
  > I worked with so little energy that I didn't (manage to) write 100 letters.'

Comment: _ne_ is not an option, right?

Comment: @Rafael, Ne is not an option, unless one were to reformulate the result clause so that it says something like '...that I managed to write not even 30 letters'; in that case, ne would be used, but only as part of a ne...quidem: ut ne triginta quidem epistulas scripserim.

Comment: I kind of expected/needed an answer in that line, thanks